# Regex not recognizing input value for vehicle license plate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, validation

I'm having a problem with my regex validation code. I'm trying to figure out how can I validate a vehicle license plate number. The code that I wrote is listed below this message. This is written down in React inline code and I've written down two different regex expressions and both of the come out to be false. The license plate number should be in this format XX-NNNN-XX.

```
X = Letter
N = Number

const [licencePlate, setLicencePlate] = useState('');

var ValidateLicencePlate = /^[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z]$/g ;
var regex = /^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{2}$/g ;

<input name="licence-plate" type="text" className="feedback-input" maxLength='10' onChange={(e) => setLicencePlate(e.target.value.toUpperCase())} placeholder="XX-NNNN-XX"/>
```

Comment: Where do you use this regexes?

Comment: try to test your regex in a web tool regexr.com/59qpc, though it looks good to me. How are you testing the regex?

Comment: hi there guys. the problem that I encountered was solved and I had problems with the test but it already got fixed :)  @LucaFaggianelli I check that site its good and helps a lot thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex can solve the problem.

```
let regex = /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-[A-Z]{2}/gi
```

This regex will match two alphabet at the beginning, four digits at the middle and two alphabet at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `regex` in the `pattern` attribute of the `input` element. I do not see you are using regexps yo have defined anywhere in your listing.

```
<input pattern={regex}/>
```

If you have a regex constraint to validate against it may be better and more comfortable to use Constraint Validation API.

```
<input pattern="your regex here"/>
```

Browser already validates everything in form elements if you constraint them with various ways like patter attribute and unless you tell it not to validate. But still I see many code bases trying to do the validation themselves. It is unnecessary since there is a way platform itself supports and does itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as following

```
<input pattern="/^[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-[A-Z]{2}/g"/>
```